# How can I create and Import Libraries in Netbeans - A Full Documented Q

Tags: java, netbeans, shared-libraries

It's me again. So here's the deal, I still don’t really grasp if I am doing something wrong.

I am trying to create my own Personal Library, in which I have certain string methods and so on.

I’ve started by creating a new Project as a Java library:

[image]

Then I've added a package to that library:

[image]

After that I've created a class in said package:

[image]

Here the code of my class:

[image]

And cleaned and built that Class//Library. `Run -> Clean and Build`
And afterwards created the JavaDoc `Run -> Generate JavaDoc(MyTestLibrary)`

After doing this i decided to add my newly created Library to the Libraries under `Tools - > Libraries`:

[image]

After that I’ve added a new Library (bottom right) and named it TestLibrary:

[image]

SO decided to add the .jar File first. I clicked on the “Add JAR/Folder... ”  Option and searched for my Projekt Folder (from MyTestLibrary) and went in to the “dist” folder and selected the .jar file:

[image]

After that I’ve added the “src”-Folder in “Sources” and the “javadoc”-Folder in “Javadoc”.

After i was finished it was time to create a new Project, to be precise a new Java Application, and try to import my freshly created library. I rightclicked on Libraries and clicked on “Add Library...”:

[image]

And imported my Test Library and adding it:

[image]

Happy that I've added my Library to my application I decided to import it 
`import TestPackage.TestClass;`.

If I try

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    TestClass.
}
```

The only suggestion is `TestClass.class` and not `TestClass.TestMethod`.

Why can't I access the methods of the “TestClass” directly?

How can I see them?

I've tried being as specific as possible. I hope this time I can fully understand what is going on and why I can't access them.

Comment: because the method isn't **static**. You have to create an instance of `TestClass` in order to run the method.

Comment: Is there a way to work around the need for static? And not use an instance?

Comment: @MilesA. If you want to use methods without an instance, no. That's how java has been designed. Static methods let you access them without the need for an instance, non-static methods cannot be used that way.

Comment: @MilesA. no. Java doesn't provide global-methods. Thus `static` methods are your best shot, if you want to use a method without creating an instance.

Comment: Since the basic concepts of Java are unclear to you, you probably shouldn't be attempting to write your own libraries either. Just a reality check here to prevent you from wasting too much time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Kayman, but the basic concept of static and non-static methods are well known to me. I was just under the wrong impression that it isn't needed to create static methods for classes in libraries in order to access them directly, eversince one already imports them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was fairly simple and obvious.

To access the methods without the need of creating an instance of the class i just had to declare them `static`.